# How do I change the index page for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know that to change the index page for rails I need to do three things: delete the index.html, do something with routes.rb, and probably make an action that the route will point to.  It's the details that I am a little fuzzy on :-)

Answer (score 13):

Ok, I figured it out.  Basically you

1. Delete public.html
2. Add 'map.root :controller => "foo"' to routes.rb
3. and then of course create the controller foo with the action index.

Answer (score 5):

Follow Frew's steps and, as step 4, put a little html code in the index view file in the /views/foo folder to test it all.

Example:

```
<h1>My New Index Page</h1>
<p>Some text here.</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to restart your server.

You can also run rake routes to show all the known routes and make sure everything looks sane.

Answer (score 1):

Please note from RoR Version 4.0 + this changed - follow the simple steps on the [getting started guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) !

It will become clear within minutes how it works.

Just thought it might be worth updating this threat, as those using a newer version might get confused and frustrated :)